# Find whether TV supports S Video

Tags: port, tv, external-display, desktop-computer

I have a TV (some unknown model) which has 3 sockets to insert 3 wires red, yellow and white. A DVD Player can be connected to the TV using sockets and the TV displays that the TV is in AV mode when DVD is running.

Now i have a Desktop which has a S Video Port and i have a wire to connect the S Video port from my computer to those red, yellow and white sockets using appropriate pins.

Now i have searched all over the remote and it does not switches to S Video Mode, it has only 2 modes of operation i.e. 
1 Cable Connection (Third Party DTH Receiver receives channels and i pay subscription) 
and 
2 AV Mode.

It does not have S Video Mode or any other mode.

Now my question is whether i can connect the S Video cable from my desktop to the above described TV or i should look for a new TV if i wish to connect the S Video from Computer to TV or there is any sort of converter that can help?

I did tried connecting the S Video cable from Desktop to TV, but it did'nt worked. TV kept on displaying Blue Screen of AV Mode.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need an s-video to RCA cable (http://www.google.com/search?q=s-video+to+rca) ([http://www.cablestogo.com/product.asp?cat_id=2012&sku=27964&cm_mmc=Google%20Base-*-Cables-*-NA-_-27964](http://www.cablestogo.com/product.asp?cat_id=2012&sku=27964&cm_mmc=Google%20Base-_-Cables-_-NA-_-27964)).

I would think that the Red and White cables are for stereo sound, and the yellow cable is the composite video.

So, get a headphone to RCA Y connector for the red and white, and get an S-Video to RCA for the yellow connector.

Comment: If by "s-video to RCA" you mean 4-pin mini-DIN to 2 x RCA, that won't help if his TV doesn't have s-video input. He can plug in the luminance channel and get a black & white picture perhaps.

Comment: The s-video to RCA cable/adapter/convert contains some electronics to combine the separate video into composite video. Not a Y connector. The Y connector is to convert the stereo headphone jack into Left and Right channel RCA plugs.

Answer (score 0):

Change your TV to AV Mode.  That should feed it the input from the composite connectors (red, white, and yellow).

Now on your desktop check your drivers for your video card. You probably need to fiddle with the settings on the PC end.